# Не удается найти путь между двумя точками

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50

struct Vertex {
   char name[100];
   bool visited;
};
struct edge
{
   int weight;
   int vertexIndex;
   struct edge *edgePtr;
};
//queue variables
int queue[MAX];
int rear = -1;
int front = 0;
int queueItemCount = 0;

 //graph variables

 //array of vertices
struct Vertex* lstVertices[MAX];

//adjacency matrix
int adjMatrix[MAX][MAX];

 //vertex count
int vertexCount = 0;

//queue functions

void insert(int data) {
   queue[++rear] = data;
   queueItemCount++;
}

int removeData() {
   queueItemCount--;
   return queue[front++]; 
   }

bool isQueueEmpty() {
   return queueItemCount == 0;
}

//graph functions

//add vertex to the vertex list
void addVertex(char *name) {
   struct Vertex* vertex = (struct Vertex*) malloc(sizeof(*vertex));
   strncpy(vertex->name, name, sizeof(name));
   vertex->visited = false;
   lstVertices[vertexCount++] = vertex;
   }

//add edge to edge array
void addEdge(int start, int end, int weight_) {
   struct edge *e = (struct edge *)malloc(sizeof(*e));
   e->weight = weight_;
   adjMatrix[start][end] = e->weight;
   adjMatrix[end][start] = e->weight;
}

//display the vertex
void displayVertex(int vertexIndex){
   printf("%s ",lstVertices[vertexIndex]->name);
}       

//get the adjacent unvisited vertex
int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int vertexIndex) {
   struct edge* e = (struct edge*)malloc(sizeof(*e));
   for(int i = 0; i<vertexCount; i++) {
      if(adjMatrix[vertexIndex][i] == e->weight && lstVertices[i]->visited == false)
         return i;
      }
      
   return -1;
   }

void Search(int src, int dst) {
   struct Vertex* vertex = (struct Vertex*) malloc(sizeof(struct Vertex));
   //mark first node as visited
   lstVertices[src]->visited = true;

   //display the vertex
   displayVertex(src);   

   //insert vertex index in queue
   insert(src);
   int unvisitedVertex;

   while(!isQueueEmpty()) {
      //get the unvisited vertex of vertex which is at front of the queue
      int tempVertex = removeData();   

      //no adjacent vertex found
      while((unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(tempVertex)) != -1) {    
         lstVertices[unvisitedVertex]->visited = true;
         displayVertex(unvisitedVertex);
         insert(unvisitedVertex);               
         }
         
      }   
      //queue is empty, search is complete, reset the visited flag        
      for(int i = 0; i<vertexCount; i++) {
         lstVertices[i]->visited = false;
      }    
   }

int main() {
   struct edge *e = (struct edge*)malloc(sizeof(*e));
   for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++){// set adjacency
   for(int j = 0; j<MAX; j++){ // matrix to 0
      adjMatrix[i][j] = 0;
   }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что отладка показывает?

Comment: @MBo Распечатывает все города
*Path Found: Prague Beijing Tokyo Jakarta New York Helsinki London [Inferior 1 (process 6764) exited normally]*

Comment: Множество загадок содержит этот код. Зачем в `addEdge()` структура `e`? Почему просто не присвоить вес? Та же история в функции `getAdjUnvisitedVertex()`, которая и не работает. Тут нужно проверить, что элемент массива больше 0. Судя по ожидаемому результату, граф должен быть ориентированным. Но в `addEdge()` вы делаете две записи в матрицу, делая его неориентированным. Сам алгоритм поиска - BFS. Выводя просто вершины, добавленные в очередь, Вы не получите маршрут. Ну и в `Search()` нет проверки, что цель достигнута, после чего и следовало бы восстановить маршрут.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Какой алгоритм поиска следует использовать?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Кстати, спасибо. Можете ли вы помочь мне исправить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, чтобы код заработал, нужно дать возможность графу быть ориентированным:

```
void addEdge(int start, int end, int weight)
{
    adjMatrix[start][end] = weight;
    //adjMatrix[end][start] = weight; // это сделает граф неориентированным
}
```

Далее, требуются корректировки функции getAdjUnvisitedVertex(). Прямой путь в вершину имеется, если значение матрицы > 0:

```
int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int vertexIndex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
        if (adjMatrix[vertexIndex][i] > 0 && lstVertices[i]->visited == false)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Чтобы иметь возможность восстановить маршрут, добавим в структуру vertex свойства from и dist:

```
struct Vertex {
    char name[100];
    bool visited;
    int from = -1;
    int dist = 0;
};
```

Функция Search(), по-хорошему, должна возвращать значение. Например, -1 - если путь не найден, индекс вершины - если найден (или true/false, не важно). Соответственно, в самой функции нужна проверка, что цель достигнута:

```
int Search(int src, int dst)
{
    lstVertices[src]->visited = true;

    insert(src);
    int unvisitedVertex;

    while (!isQueueEmpty()) {
        int tempVertex = removeData();

        while ((unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(tempVertex)) != -1) {
            
            lstVertices[unvisitedVertex]->visited = true;
            lstVertices[unvisitedVertex]->from = tempVertex;
            lstVertices[unvisitedVertex]->dist = adjMatrix[tempVertex][unvisitedVertex];
            
            // цель достигнута?
            if (unvisitedVertex == dst)  return dst; 
            
            insert(unvisitedVertex);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Функция для вывода маршрута:

```
void printRoute(int vertex)
{
    int total = 0;

    while (lstVertices[vertex]->from > -1)
    {
        displayVertex(vertex);
        total += lstVertices[vertex]->dist;
        vertex = lstVertices[vertex]->from;
    }
    displayVertex(vertex);

    printf("\nTotal distance: %d", total);
}
```

Вызов в main():

```
if (Search(0, 2) > -1) {
    printRoute(2);
}
```

Вывод маршрута в обратном порядке, но это уже совсем другая история...

P.S. Исхожу из того, что задача поиска оптимального маршрута не стоит, иначе нужен принципиально другой алгоритм.

Comment: **error: 'struct Vertex' has no member named 'from' lstVertices[unvisitedVertex]->from = tempVertex;**
Что не так?

Comment: а насчет обратного порядка, есть ли способ это изменить?

Comment: @goku По поводу ошибки, видимо Вы забыли добавить свойства from и dist в структуру Vertex, хотя я указал это в ответе. А с обратным порядком даже не знаю, задача на порядок проще. Ну запишите индексы в массив и прочитайте в обратном порядке.

Comment: Прежде всего, большое спасибо за ваше решение. Вы очень помогли, я ценю это. Вы запускали этот код на своей локальной машине? Потому что я не могу видеть общее расстояние.

Comment: @goku Да, выводит правильно. [Вот скрин](https://imgur.com/ODYJVFw). Опишите более точно проблему.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с вопросом, пожалуйста. Я получаю символы, отличные от ASCII.

Comment: @goku Вполне себе ASCII символы. Функция `addVertex()` смущает. `sizeof(name)` - это сколько, как Вы думаете? Попробуйте заменить `strncpy` на `strcpy`. И здесь же явно задайте значения `vertex->from = -1;` и `vertex->dist = 0;`, на возможность присваивать нестатическим членам структуры значения по умолчанию - это я губу раскатал.